# python unicode implementation (using external programs: cygnative plink ssh rsync)

Tags: python, utf-8, cygwin, rsync, plink

I have a backup applications in python that needs to work on Windows. It needs UTF compatibility (to be able to backup directories that contain UTF characters like italian accents). The problem is it uses external programs (plink, cygwin, ssh and rsync) and I can't get them working. The prototype is 32 lines long, please take a look:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess

def safestr(obj, encoding='utf-8'):
    r"""Converts any given object to utf-8 encoded string.

        >>> safestr('hello')
        'hello'
        >>> safestr(u'\u1234')
        '\xe1\x88\xb4'
        >>> safestr(2)
        '2'
    """
    if isinstance(obj, unicode):
        return obj.encode("utf-8")
    elif isinstance(obj, str):
        return obj.encode
    else:
        return str(obj)

def execute(command):
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, errs = pipe.communicate()
    retcode = pipe.poll()

    print "OUT: " + repr(out)
    print "ERRS: " + repr(errs)
    print "RET: " + str(retcode)


command = u'rsync --stats -az --numeric-ids --delete --blocking-io --modify-window=2 --no-group --chmod=u=rwX,g=,o=  -e \'cygnative plink -ssh -2 -batch  -pw test \' "/cygdrive/c/κόσμε" vaidab@192.168.1.86:/volatile/backup/vaidab/2010-03-03.15_41_56/ --link-dest=../2010-03-03.15_00_57'.encode('utf-8')
execute(command)
```

Still doesn't work with nosklo's version, check the result:

> python prototype_unicode_new.py
>   'rsync.exe --stats -az --numeric-ids --delete --blocking-io --modify-window=2 --
>   no-group --chmod=u=rwX,g=,o= -e "cygnative plink -ssh -2 -batch -pw test" /cygdr
>   ive/c/\xce\xba\xcf\x8c\xcf\x83\xce\xbc\xce\xb5 vaidab@192.168.1.86:/volatile/bac
>   kup/vaidab/2010-03-03.15_41_56/'

OUT: '\nNumber of files: 0\nNumber of files transferred: 0\nTotal file size: 0 b
ytes\nTotal transferred file size: 0 bytes\nLiteral data: 0 bytes\nMatched data:
 0 bytes\nFile list size: 9\nFile list generation time: 0.001 seconds\nFile list
 transfer time: 0.000 seconds\nTotal bytes sent: 22\nTotal bytes received: 12\n\
nsent 22 bytes  received 12 bytes  68.00 bytes/sec\ntotal size is 0  speedup is
0.00\n'
ERRS: 'rsync: link_stat "/cygdrive/c/\xc3\x8e\xc2\xba\xc3\x8f\xc5\x92\xc3\x8f\xc
6\x92\xc3\x8e\xc2\xbc\xc3\x8e\xc2\xb5" failed: No such file or directory (2)\nrs
ync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23)
 at /home/lapo/packaging/rsync-3.0.6-1/src/rsync-3.0.6/main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.
6]\n'
RET: 23

Comment: Please include the code in your question (there's special markup for that). You can't expect us to download a zipfile...

Comment: 32 lines is too small. Please copy the source and paste it on the question.

Comment: I included in the zipfile the binaries (rsync, cygnative, plink and ssh + dlls so you could use all the tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use `shell=True`. **EVER**. It needlessy invokes a shell to call your program.
- Pass the parameters as a list instead of a string.

This example should work, provided the parameters are right and the rsync.exe is in current folder (or `PATH`):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import subprocess

def execute(command):
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, errs = pipe.communicate()
    retcode = pipe.poll()

    print "OUT: " + repr(out)
    print "ERRS: " + repr(errs)
    print "RET: " + str(retcode)
    return out


command = ['rsync.exe', '--stats', '-az', '--numeric-ids', '--delete', 
           '--blocking-io', '--modify-window=2', '--no-group', 
           '--chmod=u=rwX,g=,o=', '-e', 
           'cygnative plink -ssh -2 -batch -pw test', 
           u'/cygdrive/c/κόσμε'.encode('utf-8'), 
           'vaidab@192.168.1.86:/volatile/backup/vaidab/2010-03-03.15_41_56/', 
           '--link-dest=../2010-03-03.15_00_57']

execute(command)
```

Comment: Well, then it seems your filesystem is not utf-8. What does `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` returns? Perhaps try using that as encoding?

Comment: it returns mbcs. I modified to .encode('mbcs') and:
>python prototype_unicode_new.py
'rsync.exe --stats -az --numeric-ids --delete --blocking-io --modify-window=2 --
no-group --chmod=u=rwX,g=,o= -e "cygnative plink -ssh -2 -batch -pw test" /cygdr
ive/c/??s\xb5e vaidab@192.168.1.86:/volatile/backup/vaidab/2010-03-03.15_41_56/'
...
ERRS: 'rsync: link_stat "/cygdrive/c/??s\xc2\xb5e" failed: No such file or direc
tory

Comment: @vaidab: are you able to run the command on the command prompt? Which encoding is your terminal/console program using?

Comment: After installing the Italian language I get:
sys.getdefaultencoding()
 ascii
sys.stdout.encoding()
 cp437

Comment: @vaidab: which editor are you using to edit the source file? Is the editor able to save the file in utf-8?

Comment: I'm using vim and the utf-8 chars I type in the source file work ok on linux (I create a directory with them and test its existence).

Answer (score 0):

A piece of code that passeth all understanding:

```
if isinstance(obj, unicode):
    return obj.encode("utf-8")
elif isinstance(obj, str):
    return obj.encode
    # the above is returning a METHOD ***************************
else:
    return str(obj)
```

What's the point of doctests if you don't run them?

Comment: true, It was a leftover, sorry for that.